# Delay in query when using TOP

Tags: sql-server, optimization

On the following query, if I run it just as "SELECT [Nominal]..." then it will execute and return over 12000 results in less than a second.

However, with the `TOP 5` takes over 7 minutes to execute, eventually coming up with the expected answer.

To get around this partially I can place it into a temporary table, and then do a `TOP 5` from there. However I need to incorporate this into a function with a variable clause for the `PrID`. But functions don't work with temporary tables. Placing the entire query in the function will reintroduce the 7 minute delay.

And finally I'm not in a position to redesign existing or create new permanent tables.

```
SELECT TOP 5
[Nominal].[OwId],
[Nominal].[PrID],
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(Archived, 0) = 0
        THEN '.\Document Store\ '
    WHEN [Archived] = 1
        THEN '.\Archive Store\ '
    END +
CASE
    WHEN [Documents].Spare1 IS NOT NULL
        THEN CONVERT(nVarChar(50),[Documents].Spare1)
    WHEN [Documents].Spare1 IS NULL
        THEN CONVERT(nVarChar(50),[Documents].ID)
    END
    + '.pdf' AS [File Name],
[Documents].[Date],
[Nominal].[Statement Number],
[Nominal].[Total]
FROM [Documents]
    INNER JOIN [Nominal]
    ON [Document Name] = 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            'Statement - ' 
                + [account] 
                + ' ' 
                + CONVERT(nVarChar(50),[Statement Number]),
            '/',
            ' '),
        ',',
        '')
ORDER BY [Statement Number];
```

EDIT, in reply to comments:

I'm not well versed in all of this, I had to google most of the comment. Now I can see what the problems is:

Without TOP 5, the most costly is a Hash Match (Inner Join), Cost: 76%
 Expected and as the whole thing takes just a few seconds not a problem.

With TOP 5, the most costly is a Table Scan [Documents], Cost: 100%
 The Inner Joins appear to have been replaced with two Nested Loops (Not sure the exact difference of Nested Loops and Hash Matches and why it needs two but the cost isn't there)

Pointers anyone?

Comment: Well, is there an index on `[Statement Number]`? What is its data type? Did you look at the execution plan? I bet there is a very expensive sort in the TOP 5 version that isn't in the other version.

Comment: Have you compared the two execution plans to see the differences?

Comment: @Aaron: According to the OP the "ORDER BY [Statement Number]" exists in both queries.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'm not convinced that's true. Just because of their first sentence it doesn't necessarily mean the non-`TOP` version also has an `ORDER BY`. Let's let the OP specify that explicitly, ok?

Comment: @Aaron: I am thinking two different execution plans are cached; one for each version.

Comment: @Pieter maybe. My suggestion was a guess too.

Comment: @Nutter4ever: Is the "ORDER BY [Statement Number]" in both queries?

Comment: Seeing as we are guessing my one is that the `TOP 5` query has a nested loops join driven by an index scan on `Nominal.[Statement Number]`  and many more scans of `Documents` on the inner side than estimated. If you post the execution plans perhaps we wouldn't have to guess though...

Comment: @Everyone who has kindly replied... I've changed the original post, as this doesn't allow <enter>